# Change text of selected option only

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

I am stucking with a problem. I have a select box with multiple options

```
<select name="p_hour">
<option value="00">12 am</option>
<option value="01">1 am</option>
<option value="02">2 am</option>
<option value="03">3 am</option>
<option value="04">4 am</option>
<option value="05">5 am</option>
<option value="06">6 am</option>
<option value="07">7 am</option>
<option value="08">8 am</option>
<option value="09">9 am</option>
<option value="10">10 am</option>
</select>
```

What I want to achieve is when someone made a selection the text in the option should change to the number only without am/pm. The code is

```
jQuery("select[name='p_hour']").on('change', function() {
    $selectedval = jQuery("select[name='p_hour'] option:selected").text();
    $selectedval = $selectedval.slice(0,-2);
    jQuery("select[name='p_hour'] option:selected").text($selectedval);
    $selectedval = '';
});
```

But the problem is the the text of the option remains number only if another selection is made, I want to change the text only for selected option only. Can anyone help me?

Comment: working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/92/

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for instance you selected 1 am, it will become 1. But if I change the value (say 3 am), 1 should be back to 1 am and 3 am to 3. Is that about right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the most elegant way, but try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var selectedval, $select = $("select[name='p_hour']"),
        $prev;
    $select.on('change', function () {
        var $cur = $select.find("option:selected")
        if ($prev) {
            if ($prev.is($cur)) {
                return;
            }
            $prev.text(selectedval);
        }
        selectedval = $cur.text();
        $cur.text(selectedval.slice(0, -2));
        $prev = $cur
    }).change()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j3Uwu/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're missing `);` to close your `.on()` handler and make sure you've put your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("select[name='p_hour']").on('change', function () {
        $selectedval = jQuery("select[name='p_hour'] option:selected").text();
        $selectedval = $selectedval.slice(0, -2);
        alert($selectedval);
        jQuery("select[name='p_hour'] option:selected").text($selectedval);
        $selectedval = '';
    }); // <-- Here
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fq5r/2/)**

Comment: sorry that was a typo error, i have edited my question please see what I want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is if 1 am from the dropdown it changes 1 and if made another selection the 1 remains I want only the selected option's text to be changed